# Which colleges in the US are researching Astrionics/ Space communication systems?

Tags: communication, research, avionics

An example is the [Space Engineering Research Center](http://www.isi.edu/centers/serc/home) at University of Southern California Viterbi School of Engineering. What other colleges in the US are contributing to research on these topics?